# Do Covering Projections fulfill the relations of fibrations?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

In "Algebraic Topology" of Spanier, he proves on page 67 that

> A covering projection is a fibration.

Two pages later he writes

> We have seen that a covering projection is a fibration with unique path lifting. [...] One reason for studying fibrations with unique path lifting as generalized covering projections is that the following two theorems are easily proved, but both are false for covering projections.

The book continuous with a theorem:

> Theorem 6: The composite of fibrations (with unique path lifting) is a
>   fibration (with unique path lifting).

and then says

> An example shows that theorem 6 is false for covering projections.

How can this be true? If a more specific thing (like a dog) is a more general thing (like an animal) and I prove a theorem for the general thing (the animal - e.g. all animals are living beings) then this should be true for the specific thing (the dog) too or not?

It seems somehow that there is a misunderstanding on my side concerning Spaniers meaning. Could someone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Without thinking too hard about it, I would say that these passages imply the composite of covering projections is a fibration but not necessarily a covering projection.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Thanks - that could really be it. I was confused that he wrote that the theorem is false for Covering Spaces which would be a contradiction but you are probably right in that he meant "If you replace fibration *everywhere* by "Covering Space" then it is not true anymore.

Comment: Maybe it's like: If you mix marbles with marbles, you get marbles but if you mix blue marbles with red marbles you don't get marbles with one color?